# HTML CSS: How to add Sliding Header?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In Boostrap Slide show carousel, how would I add my descriptions to the title above instead of below at the captions sliding? I am trying to find Bootstrap functionality to conduct this, but I cannot locate it. It is sliding in the below pictures, I want to place it at the top where green box is.

Does Bootstrap allow this functionality?

```css
.carousel-inner {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
}

.carouselheader {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 32px;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-left-width: 1px;
}

.carousel slide {
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.carouselleftarrow {
  font-family: Material Icons;
  font-size: 36px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  content: "\e408";
  color: black;
}

.carouselleftarrow:hover {
  color: black;
}

.carouselrightarrow {
  font-family: Material Icons;
  font-size: 36px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  content: "\e409";
  color: black;
}

.carouselrightarrow:hover {
  color: black;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
  text-indent: 0 !important;
  width: 24px !important;
  height: 24px !important;
  margin: 3px !important;
  border-radius: 50px !important;
  bottom: 3px;
  font: 10px;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  color: #999999;
  background-color: blue;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.carousel-indicators li.active {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

.carousel-indicators li:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

.left .carousel-control {
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-image: none;
}

.right .carousel-control {
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-image: none;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.carousel-control.left {
  background-image: none;
}

.carousel-control.right {
  background-image: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<ipts-carousel>
  <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="Carouselid9a15830fddaa4c479b693696f4c9690c" style="  width: 500px;
                         height: 516px;">
    <div class="carouselheader">Place Descriptions in Top Here</div>
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-slide-to="0" data-target="#Carouselid9a15830fddaa4c479b693696f4c9690c" class="">1</li>
      <li data-slide-to="1" data-target="#Carouselid9a15830fddaa4c479b693696f4c9690c" class="">2</li>
      <li data-slide-to="2" data-target="#Carouselid9a15830fddaa4c479b693696f4c9690c" class="active">3</li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" style="height: 500px;">
      <div class="item carousel" style="width: 500px;  
                    height:500px; height: 100%;"><img class="imgcarousel mCS_img_loaded" src="https://img1.10bestmedia.com/Images/Photos/352450/GettyImages-913753556_54_990x660.jpg" style="width: 500px;  
                    height:500px; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Ocean sea</h3>
          <p>Ocean Sea has nice view</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item carousel" style="width: 500px;  
                    height:500px; height: 100%;"><img class="imgcarousel mCS_img_loaded" src="https://amp.businessinsider.com/images/5b75a356e199f336008b528b-750-563.jpg" style="width: 500px;  
                    height:500px; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Nice Houses</h3>
          <p>Neighboor houses in Chicago</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item carousel active" style="width: 500px;  
                    height:500px; height: 100%;"><img class="imgcarousel mCS_img_loaded" src="https://www.mcpl.us/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/bookstack.jpg?itok=pHICdzg9" style="width: 500px;  
                    height:500px; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Reading Books</h3>
          <p>Stack of library books</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><a class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev" href="#Carouselid9a15830fddaa4c479b693696f4c9690c"><span class="carouselleftarrow">navigate_before</span></a><a class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next" href="#Carouselid9a15830fddaa4c479b693696f4c9690c"
      style="display: inline-flex;"><span class="carouselrightarrow">navigate_next</span></a></div>
</ipts-carousel>
```

Comment: So you want the title, e.g. "Ocean Sea" title to stay where it is, but have "Ocean Sea has nice view" to go into the green area?

Comment: This question is being [discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387153/can-i-do-anything-about-multiple-rejected-edits-by-the-asker-that-were-just-adde).

Comment: uh not sure what goal is here. just a question

Comment: beautiful summer day outside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some adaptations...

#### Live example:

```css
.carousel-inner {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
}

.carousel slide {
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.carouselleftarrow {
  font-family: Material Icons;
  font-size: 36px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  content: "\e408";
  color: black;
}

.carouselleftarrow:hover {
  color: black;
}

.carouselrightarrow {
  font-family: Material Icons;
  font-size: 36px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  content: "\e409";
  color: black;
}

.carouselrightarrow:hover {
  color: black;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
  text-indent: 0 !important;
  width: 24px !important;
  height: 24px !important;
  margin: 3px !important;
  border-radius: 50px !important;
  bottom: 3px;
  font: 10px;
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  color: #999999;
  background-color: blue;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.carousel-indicators li.active {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

.carousel-indicators li:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

.left .carousel-control {
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-image: none;
}

.right .carousel-control {
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-image: none;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.carousel-control.left {
  background-image: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.carousel-control.right {
  background-image: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.carousel-caption {
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  padding: 8px !important;
  text-align: center;
  background: green;
  color: white;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 69px;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-left-width: 1px;
  right: 0 !important;
  left: 0 !important;
}

.carousel-caption h3 {
  margin: 0px;
}

.carousel-caption p {
  margin: 0px;
}

.carousel-inner>.item>a>img,
.carousel-inner>.item>img {
  top: 69px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<ipts-carousel>
  <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="Carouselid9a15830fddaa4c479b693696f4c9690c" style="  width: 500px;
                         height: 516px;">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-slide-to="0" data-target="#Carouselid9a15830fddaa4c479b693696f4c9690c" class="">1</li>
      <li data-slide-to="1" data-target="#Carouselid9a15830fddaa4c479b693696f4c9690c" class="">2</li>
      <li data-slide-to="2" data-target="#Carouselid9a15830fddaa4c479b693696f4c9690c" class="active">3</li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" style="height: 100%;">
      <div class="item carousel" style="width: 500px;  
                    height:500px; height: 100%;"><img class="imgcarousel mCS_img_loaded" src="https://img1.10bestmedia.com/Images/Photos/352450/GettyImages-913753556_54_990x660.jpg" style="width: 500px;  
                    height:500px; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Ocean sea</h3>
          <p>Ocean Sea has nice view</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item carousel" style="width: 500px;  
                    height:500px; height: 100%;"><img class="imgcarousel mCS_img_loaded" src="https://amp.businessinsider.com/images/5b75a356e199f336008b528b-750-563.jpg" style="width: 500px;  
                    height:500px; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Nice Houses</h3>
          <p>Neighboor houses in Chicago</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item carousel active" style="width: 500px;  
                    height:500px; height: 100%;"><img class="imgcarousel mCS_img_loaded" src="https://www.mcpl.us/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/bookstack.jpg?itok=pHICdzg9" style="width: 500px;  
                    height:500px; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Reading Books</h3>
          <p>Stack of library books</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><a class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev" href="#Carouselid9a15830fddaa4c479b693696f4c9690c"><span class="carouselleftarrow">navigate_before</span></a><a class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next" href="#Carouselid9a15830fddaa4c479b693696f4c9690c"
      style="display: inline-flex;"><span class="carouselrightarrow">navigate_next</span></a></div>
</ipts-carousel>
```

Comment: Explanation...?